# terraform not expanding [count.index]

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I'm learning terraform and I do not understand why the variable `count.index` isn't being expanded.

When I run `terraform apply` the name of the EC2 instance becomes `VM[count.index]`

Why doesn't [count.index] become expanded? I was expecting the name to be `VM0`

file I created for testing

`main.tf`

```
provider "aws" {
  access_key = var.aws_access_key_id
  secret_key = var.aws_secret_access_key
  region     = "us-east-1"
}

resource "aws_instance" "aws_vm" {
  ami           = var.ami
  instance_type = var.type
  count         = var.number_of_instances
  key_name      = var.ami_key

  tags = {
    Name = "${var.name_tag}[count.index]"
  }
}
```

Comment: I would say that you should rewrite the tag Name in "${var.name_tag}${count.index}"

Comment: For your future reference, it's more common to ask why a variable is not "incrementing" rather than "expanding"

Comment: @JohnSkilesSkinner "expanding" is the correct term here. They are trying to "expand" or "interpolate" the variable inside of a string. They are not trying to increment a variable here. The variable is already being automatically incremented, they are just trying to convert it to a string.

Comment: Ah, you are correct. I guess I was in need of coffee when I wrote that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Terraform [string interpolation](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/expressions/strings) only happens inside a `${}`. You have to wrap any variables or expressions embedded in a string in a `${}`. You've done that with the `var_name_tag` variable, but not the `count.index` variable. Change your code to this:

```
  tags = {
    Name = "${var.name_tag}[${count.index}]"
  }
```

So if `var.name_tag` was a string value like `"my_server"`, then you would end up with name tags on your EC2 instances with values like: `my_server[0]` and `my_server[1]`